# Fetching a particular value in XSL 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

```
<soap:Envelope>
    <soap:Header>
        <eb:Messaging eb:version="3.0" id="ebMessage" soap:mustUnderstand="1">
            <eb:UserMessage>
                <eb:PartyInfo>
                    <eb:From>
                        <eb:PartyId/>
                        <eb:Role>Sender</eb:Role>
                    </eb:From>
                </eb:PartyInfo>
            </eb:UserMessage>
        </eb:Messaging>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
    <Response>
            <cac:Seller>
                <cac:Party>
                    <cac:PartyIdentification>
                        <cbc:ID>123412341234</cbc:ID>
                    </cac:PartyIdentification>
                </cac:Party>
            </cac:Seller>
        </Response> 
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Input xml is as shown above.

My problem is I have to pick path for element `"eb:PartyId"` from the element `"cac:Seller/cac:Party/cac:PartyIdentification/cbc:ID"`

The value of Seller Party ID(123412341234) should come in eb:PartyID.

I have tried -

```
../../../../../soap:Body/Response/cac:Seller/cac:Party/cac:PartyIdentification/cbc:ID
```

&

Used Descendants but I am not able to fetch the value for it.

Please suggest.

Comment: You should use SOAP here, not XPath.

Comment: but `eb:PartyId` is empty, there is no value here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
preceding::eb:PartyId[1]
```